# Canvas Game Architecture: Access parent function in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine, javascript-objects

I am trying to understand how can I create a custom game object in javascript.I am working on canvas and I thought that I can create a general game object that includes information about objects position,shape etc. and functions like "move", "fire", "display" etc.

I created a function called "create(canvas)". That gets the canvas and initializes the local variables then calls the display function in "onload" function.
But I can not access display function of an object.
Additionally, I  always use "this" syntax to access my local variables or functions. It makes me feel that there is something going wrong.

You can see the code below

```
<script>


    var gameObject = {

        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        velocity: 5,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        triggerObject:null,
        imgUrl: "/assets/minionframe/1.png",
        img:null,
        canvas:null,
        context:null,
        display:function(){
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

            this.context.drawImage(this.img,this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
        },
        move: function (direction) {
            if (direction == "right")
                x += this.velocity;
            else if (direction == "left")
                x -= this.velocity;
            else if (direction == "up")
                y -= this.velocity;
            else if (direction == "down")
                y += this.velocity;
            this.display();
        },
        fire: function () {

        },
        create: function (canvas) {
            this.canvas = canvas;
            this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            img = new Image();
            img.src = this.imgUrl;
            img.onload = function () {
                this.display()//i cant doing this :(
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

</script>
<canvas id="scene" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script>

    var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    var obj = gameObject.create(scene);


</script>
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise not to use `this`, and to separate logic and state/data instead.

Conceptually, your game could be structured as follows:

- **state**: An object describing the current state of the world, i.e. objects with their positions, velocities, colors, ...
- **update function**: This function is called with every game step. It takes the current state of the world and the user input, and returns a new state.
- **render function**: It takes the state of the world, and draws it to the screen.

Your game logic can then be summarized like this:

```
// initialize state
const state = { /*...*/ }

// set up game loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  userInput = getUserInput();
  state = update(state, userInput);
  render(state);
});
```

Why? The different parts of your game like core logic, rendering and reading user input should know as less as possible about each other - that way you can develop them independently from each other.

Also separating the game state from it's logic helps a lot, not only to develop a clear "mental model" of your game. Just imagine you want to implement a saving/loading feature - all you'd have to do is serialize/deserialize your game state.

I tried to apply this concept to your code:

```js
var state = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  velocity: 5,
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  triggerObject: null,
  imgUrl: "/assets/minionframe/1.png"
  img: null
}

function display(context, state) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(state.img, state.x, state.y, state.width, state.height);
}

function move(direction, state) {
  if (direction == "right")
    state.x += state.velocity;
  else if (direction == "left")
    state.x -= state.velocity;
  else if (direction == "up")
    state.y -= state.velocity;
  else if (direction == "down")
    state.y += state.velocity;
  
  return state;
}

function loadImage(state) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = state.imgUrl;
  state.img = img
}

var context = document.getElementById('scene').getContext('2d');
loadImage(state);

// some kind of game loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var direction = "right"; // TODO read from user input
    state = move(direction, state);
    display(context, state)
})
```

However, this is still not perfectly separated:

- It would be ideal if `display` (our render function) would not need the argument `context`. Maybe it should initialize the canvas itself, when it is first run?
- `img` and `imgUrl` are redundant. Maybe it would make sense to drop `imgUrl` and set `img` during initialization?

I hope this helps to get you started anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it gives me another perspective to game development approach.  I though javascript object act like other object-oriented programming languages like C# or Java. So , I was trying to build a structure like Java Object.

Comment: "img" is an appearance of an object. I though it could be part of my game object.

Comment: You're welcome! I've found a functional style in JS development to work better than the "classic" OO style, and the design above is inspired by a more functional style. As for your comment about `img`, i updated my answer (see the comment in the end)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of using `this` directly store this in local variable `_thisRef`.

check out your updated code.

```
<script>


    var gameObject = function (){

        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        velocity: 5,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        triggerObject:null,
        imgUrl: "/assets/minionframe/1.png",
        img:null,
        canvas:null,
        context:null,
        _thisRef:this,  //storing this refrence.
        display:function(){
            _thisRef.context.clearRect(0, 0, _thisRef.canvas.width, _thisRef.canvas.height);

            _thisRef.context.drawImage(_thisRef.img,_thisRef.x,_thisRef.y,_thisRef.width,_thisRef.height);
        },
        move: function (direction) {
            if (direction == "right")
                x += _thisRef.velocity;
            else if (direction == "left")
                x -= _thisRef.velocity;
            else if (direction == "up")
                y -= _thisRef.velocity;
            else if (direction == "down")
                y += _thisRef.velocity;
            _thisRef.display();
        },
        fire: function () {

        },
        create: function (canvas) {
            _thisRef.canvas = canvas;
            _thisRef.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            img = new Image();
            img.src = _thisRef.imgUrl;
            img.onload = function () {

            }
            //return _thisRef;   //no need
        }
    }

</script>
<canvas id="scene" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script>

    var scene = document.getElementById('scene');

    var obj = gameObject.create(scene);

   var obj = new gameObject(); //creating object of gameObject class.
   obj.create(scene); //passing Canvas element.
   obj.display();  // this will call display function.

</script>
```

Comment: whats the difference between using "_thisRef.imgUrl" or directly using "imgUrl".

Comment: There is no as such difference if there is no local variable with same name. 
Means if there is imgUrl variable within that function and you are using it directly then it will refer that local variable instead of class level variable.